# Adding a previously defined macro to the macro ring in Emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I've been using kmacro commands such as `kmacro-name-last-macro` to save keyboard macros. The problem is that after I have saved a macro and even added it to my .emacs file, I come across an error and want to edit the macro using `kmacro-step-edit-macro`. If my named macro is no longer in the macro ring (the default `kmacro-ring-max` is 8) I can't use any of the editing or macro ring commands on that macro. After learning that `name-last-kbd-macro` will save the symbol form which is easier to edit, I regret using `kmacro-name-last-macro` and wonder why it is the new default.

Is there are way to add a previously defined macro to the macro ring so I can edit it with `kmacro-step-edit-macro`?

Comment: note that you can edit named macros using `M-x edit-named-kbd-macro`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to add a previously defined macro to the macro ring so you can edit it with kmacro-step-edit-macro :

Imagine you have named a keyboard macro tata using `name-last-kbd-macro`, and done a `insert-kbd-macro` for tata. For example :

```
(fset 'tata
   [return return ?f ?o ?o return])
```

You can store this macro definition into your .emacs for later use. On a new emacs session, you can use the following lisp code to put back your macro into your kmacro-ring :

```
(kmacro-push-ring (list 'tata 0 "%d"))
(kmacro-pop-ring)
```

After that, you can do a `kmacro-step-edit-macro` on it.

If you have named your macro using `kmacro-name-last-macro` instead of `name-last-kbd-macro`, the call to `insert-kbd-macro` will insert a different definition for your macro, using a lambda function instead of a vector or a string (to be able to store the current counter), for example :

```
(fset 'tata
   (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p")
   (kmacro-exec-ring-item
      (quote ([return return 102 111 111 return] 0 "%d")) arg)))
```

In this case, `kmacro-step-edit-macro` raises an error as this is not a vector or a string. To solve this problem you can :

- either transform your lambda function to a classic vector macro definition (like, for example, the top definition of tata above). It is normally always possible to do this kind of transformation.
- or define a macro that calls your lambda function macro, for example : `(fset 'foo [?\M-x ?t ?a ?t ?a return])` And then you can place this foo macro into the kmacro ring as said before. But in this case, you could have some side-effects at the end of the macro execution.

Comment: I get an error:
`Keyboard macros must be strings or vectors.`

That may well work for macros defined by `name-last-kbd-macro` but it doesn't seem to work with `kmacro-name-last-macro`. I have a macro stored in my .emacs file but its format is:

    (fset 'macroname
   (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([134217788 ... 25 return] 0 "%d")) arg)))

Comment: I don't know if it's possible for your case, but you could modify your macro definition macroname to a vector by removing all the command statements and leaving only [1342...25 return]


One other solution is to define a vector calling your macro, for example :


(fset 'foo [?\M-x ?m ?a ?c ?r ?o ?n ?a ?m ?e return])